# Управление гитом с разных ОС

Tags: git, github

Есть репозиторий, работал с ним всегда в windows, купил iMAC, смогу ли я продолжить работу с репозиторием с mac os? так же пушить в него работать с ветками только с другой ОС ? или нужно создавать новый репозиторий под гит клиент из mac os?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никаких проблем в общем случае возникнуть не должно - просто работайте как и раньше. Репозиторий это просто набор файлов и не важно с какой ОС вы их открываете/редактируете.

Единственное, что может случиться - `CRLF` из-за разницы чего-то там (вроде символы переноса строк) на разных ОС. Решается это, вроде, [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31144141/3212712):

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf false
$ git config --global core.safecrlf false
```

Comment: На старых версиях git'а (кажется 1.7 и более древние) могла быть проблема с не-ascii символами в именах файлов. Сейчас ее уже нет.